# Graphs in .NET CF

Tags: c#, .net, compact-framework, graph

I'm looking for a decent free control, library, or tutorial that allow graphing on .NET CF... I'm currently using v2.0 but can probably upgrade to 3.5.

I will also want to be able to save the graph as an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two years ago i did nearly the same search and found several one, but nothing really excited me. Here are my old result:

- [Mooseworks Trend Graph Control](http://www.mooseworkssoftware.com/TrendGraph.htm)
- [MindFusion PocketChart](http://www.mindfusion.eu/pocketchart.html)
- [Steema TeeChart](http://www.steema.com/teechart/net)
- [QCChart2D CF Charting Tools](http://quinn-curtis.com/QCChart2DCFProdPage.htm)
- [QCRTGraph CF - Real-Time Graphics Tools](http://quinn-curtis.com/QCRTGraphCFProdPage.htm)

Maybe one or all of them released new versions in the meantime with better performance, but better check it for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

How much functionality do you actually need?

For a CF project I did in the past, we just used a few bitmaps as the background grid and drew the plots on there. It was pretty simple and low-tech, but I was surprised at how well it served us.

Comment: Literally that... I was reserving that for my backup plan